# Rails ActiveRecord update attribute from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to use the `.to_sym` with no luck. Don't even know if this is possible.

I want to update an attribute from an active record based on a string parameter:

```
  def update_settings(type, value)
    value = ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(value)
    case type
    when 'sync_spotify'
      update(sync_spotify: value)
    when 'allowed_use_google_token'
      update(allowed_use_google_token: value)
    when 'allowed_use_spotify_token'
      update(allowed_use_spotify_token: value)
    when 'locale'
      update(locale: value)
    end
  end
```

The `type` parameter will always match the column name in the database.
Any clue? Is this even possible?

Comment: what does the beginning of the case statement look like? What result are you getting? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of the switch in `update_settings`?
`update(type => value)` can be done but you need some kind of sanity check on `type` to not expose sensitive attributes. Also 
[ActiveRecord update_attribute](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute)

Comment: Yes. That's that I want if possible.

Comment: I think I tried update_attribute(name, value) before but it didn't work. I'll check it again.

Answer (score 2):

You can define some allowed list to check if updating attribute is in this list

And then update dynamically

Something like this

```rb
BOOLEANS_ALLOWED_FOR_UPDATE = %i[
  sync_spotify
  allowed_use_google_token
  allowed_use_spotify_token
  locale
].freeze

def update_settings(type, value)
  type = type.to_sym

  raise ArgumentError unless BOOLEANS_ALLOWED_FOR_UPDATE.include?(type)

  value = ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(value)

  update(type => value)
end
```

Of course you can raise some custom error, or add error to the model instance, or just return. But in any case it is worth using some guard clause before updating

Answer (score 0):

can you try following?

```
def update_settings(type, value)
  value = ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(value)
  case type
  when 'sync_spotify'
    update(sync_spotify: value)
  when 'allowed_use_google_token'
    update(allowed_use_google_token: value)
  when 'allowed_use_spotify_token'
    update(allowed_use_spotify_token: value)
  when 'locale'
    update(locale: value)
  else
    # If the type parameter doesn't match any of the column names, 
    # raise an error or handle it in some other way
    raise ArgumentError.new("Invalid type parameter: #{type}")
  end
end
```

You can replace the `update` method calls in each case with the following code:

```
send("#{type}=", value)
```